# Susy: positioning of element in root context

Tags: compass-sass, sass, susy-compass

This is my first time using Susy. I really like what I'm seeing in the docs / tutorials, but I've encountered some unexpected results with some of my first layout attempts.

Version info:

```
>gem install compass-susy-plugin
Successfully installed sass-3.1.2
Successfully installed chunky_png-1.2.0
Successfully installed fssm-0.2.7
Successfully installed compass-0.11.1
Successfully installed compass-susy-plugin-0.9

>ruby --version
ruby 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365) [x86_64-darwin10.5.0]
```

The image below shows the result I'm getting using the [tutorial](http://susy.oddbird.net/tutorial/) html and screen.scss verbatim:

[image: why_is_the_h1_off_the_grid_somewhat]

As you can see, inspecting the h1 element shows it sitting just off the grid. Is this normal?

Answer (score 2):

See my comment on [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9273119/edit):

> Susy isn't just another grid system like all the others. It was
>   designed to fulfill a very specific purpose: grids that are [fluid on
>   the inside](https://github.com/ericam/compass-susy-plugin/blob/master/README.mkdn). The units you use to create the grid are applied to
>   the container, not to each column. Everything inside is built with
>   percentages. What you are seeing is normal. It's true of all fluid
>   grids, because of [sub-pixel rounding](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/). It's not a bug, it's a part
>   of building responsive web sites.
>
> If you need pixel-exact grids, Susy is the wrong tool for you. It all
>   depends what you are trying to build.
>
> Re-size your browser to see how it works. You'll notice the grids
>   snapping-to and floating within a few pixels of their guides, but the
>   grid stays intact and never triggers the horizontal scroll-bar.

Cheers!

-e

Answer (score 1):

If I slowly expand the browser window in Chrome vs Firefox, the grid and text jump around more in Chrome than Firefox.  It appears Firefox is more precise with the layout (which may impose a rendering speed penalty).

In Firefox, everything always lines up perfectly and moves together -- the text areas and the grid -- as I resize.  In Chrome, I can see the footer text moving at different times vs the article text vs the grid vs etc., as I resize.

Here's an example where the text and the grid were off by quite a few pixels in Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Chrome used to struggle with sub-pixel rounding in backgrounds. You'll notice it is the background that does the jumping, not the columns themselves. Or, you'd notice that on an older version of Chrome. I can't recreate this any more.